# Jquery target role=main aria

Tags: jquery, wai-aria

I am trying to target my role=main div for an ajaxish load in jQuery and I am not sure how to go about it? Do I just use [role=main] or is there another syntax.

Also if this not advisable for some reason please let me know.

Comment: Did you try [role=main]?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Found the error stoping it. Had "main" rather than just role=main. I am leaving this in case somebody else does something silly. Sorry

Comment: Can you post the above comment as answer, so that it is easy to find the answer and to make the question complete.